# Handling cookies with Flex for Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex, rubyamf

I'm using Flex 4(beta2) with Ruby on Rails 2.3.5 and using RubyAMF to transfer data back and forth between Flex and server.

I set up Authlogic on the Rails side for authentication.

I wasn't sure what's the best method to handle user sessions. I know this is done automatically with Rails by sending session id with cookie which Rails use to authenticate the user.

What do you suggest the best way to do this with Flex?

I thought of couple of options:
 1.   Manually fetching the cookie from     the browser and then figuring our a     way to send that to the server with     every request I send. 

2. Handling     sessions expiration and flow on Flex side by manually expiring the      session

Do you have other suggestion or recommendation?

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network requests in Flash use the browser networking stack so cookies in Flex work just like any other browser application.  Usually authentication in Flex is no different than it is with a standard web application.  Send credentials to the server which it correlates with a session id.  Every subsequent request (RemoteObject, HTTPService, etc) also sends that session id.

Answer (score 1):

We have seen that the flash plug-in propagates the session cookie when we do blazeDS (http) remote calls

Answer (score 1):

In the past we have worked with BlaseDS and HTTPServices. In both the cases the request is sent to the server over HTTP. Our server stack as Java (JBoss to be specific).

We noticed that the flex client used to send the session information with the requests to the server. We used same information to store and fetch Principal on the server.

In one case, we propagated the token to the client. This was to avoid multiple submits for same requests - hence we used the common HTML submission approach of token generation where with every response carries with itself a new token and the client has to sent it back to the server for executing the next request.

For the session expiration, there is a good chance that a user is working on the client for any local needs and not working with the server which may have caused a expiration on the server without impacting the server. In this case, we disabled the session expiration on the server and wrote custom code to handle events - keyboard and mouse on the flex client. If the application was not used for a specified time, the flex client would expire both the sessions i.e. local and server

Answer (score 1):

**What do you suggest the best way to do this with Flex?**

```
$loggedIn=Authenticate::isAuthenticated();
if(!$loggedIn)return false;
$user=Authenticate::getAuthUser();
```

First Authenticate the user and if he is logged in create the session. Include this in your every PHP or Ruby file, and check it. Send the Session ID to Flex to maintain the state and you set the time for your session to expire.

The above code does check, whether the user is authenticate to access the PHP or ruby class files.